# How to show overlay on Plyr (html5 video player) when in Fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, plyr

I have an application that plays SVG overlayed an HTMl5 vido tag (using Plyr HTML5 player). This works great until the user clicks the "Enter Fullscreen" option. This worked when using a previous defunct player. I would get notification and adjust my overlay accordingly, but this just does not work with Plyr.

I think what is happening is Plyr is uing the browsers (specifically chrome) Fullscreen API to do some of this work, which precludes anything else being fullscreen and on top (via z-index, etc).

I'd like to figure out how to do my overlays in fullscreen mode. This could involve:
1) something I have missed or misunderstood with Plyr, or
2) force Plyr into fallback mode (any ideas how to do this?)

Looking for some good suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, took a bit, then I forgot about this questions, so I'll answer it with what I did.

```
let plyrVideoWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__video_wrapper')
if (plyrVideoWrapper) {
    let myPluginCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('svg-embedded')
    if (myPluginCollection) {
        plyrVideoWrapper[0].appendChild(myPluginCollection[0])
    }
}
```

This basically moves my overlay plug-in, into the plyr area that has the `<video>` tag. I use the following CSS for my `'svg-embedded'`:

```
.svg-embedded {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Plyr with React, here how you implement the @Hawkeye64 solution.

- Implement your `Overlay` component and put together with your `video` component render:

```
    <Overlay />
    <video ref={innerRef} className="plyr" .../>
```

- Use `useEffect` to check when the `innerRef` is rendered and ready, and move your `Overlay` component to the Plyr's video wrapper:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (innerRef.current) {
        const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("plyr__video-wrapper");
        if (wrapper) {
          const overlay = document.getElementById("my_overlay_id");
          wrapper[0].appendChild(overlay);
        }
      }
    }, [innerRef]);
```

> Make sure to implement an `id` in your `Overlay` component, so you can retrieve using the `getElementById`, replace the `my_overlay_id` by yours in the code above.

> If you want to overlay the all video area, use the CSS below as an starting point:

```
    .overlay {
      background-color: rgba(56, 3, 3, 0.66);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better and more correct solution if you're using React is using react-portal like so:

```
import { Portal } from 'react-portal';

...

<Portal node={(document && document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__controls')[0])}>
 Your overlay here...
</Portal>
```

if you want your overlay to be part of controls,
Or if you want to be always visible:

```
<Portal node={(document && document.getElementsByClassName('plyr__video-wrapper')[0])}>
 Your overlay here...
</Portal>
```